# shouldn't I dispatch an action inside a .then statement?

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, react-redux

I found a code on git which I'm trying to understand and in the code the guy have this function:

```
export function startAddTodo(text) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const UID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const todo = {
      text,
      isDone: false,
      isStarred: false
    };
    const todoRef = firebaseRef.child(`todos/${UID}`).push(todo);

    dispatch(addTodo({
      id: todoRef.key,
      ...todo
    }));

    todoRef.then(snapshot => {
      return;
    }, error => {
      Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(error.message));
    });
  };
}
```

Why shouldn't it be like

```
const todoRef = firebaseRef.child(`todos/${UID}`).push(todo);

todoRef.then(snapshot => {

  dispatch(addTodo({
      id: snapshot.key,
      ...todo
    }));
})
```

I think this because the promise may be rejected, but in the first code he may get an error when trying to call todoRef.key inside the dispatch method.

Comment: I believe what he is doing is, not waiting for `push` to finish in order to dispatch an action. Only thing that he needs is `key`. I think in firebase you get the key when you do `.child()`. You can use .then if your next code is dependent on the value from async code. But in his case, he only needs a key.

Comment: Makes sense if your hypothesis (get the key with .child()) is valid, thank u, i'll look for it